# Dynamic TableLayoutPanel Controls Keep Border Width

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

By default I have a TableLayoutPanel with 1 column and three rows. The top and bottom rows have child TableLayoutPanels that contains buttons whereas the middle row has a TextBox. The buttons in the top and bottom rows are dynamically shown upon load based on values in My.Settings and by default there are five buttons (and therefore five columns).

The way that I'm dynamically setting the button's Text as well as if they're to be removed is as such (repeated four more times):

```
Dim visibleButtonCount As Integer = {My.Settings.ValueVisible1, My.Settings.ValueVisible2, My.Settings.ValueVisible3, My.Settings.ValueVisible4, My.Settings.ValueVisible5}.Where(Function(setting) setting).Count()
Dim buttonWidth As Double = 100 / visibleButtonCount

ButtonValueDown1.Text = $"- {My.Settings.Value1.ToString("N3")}"
ButtonValueUp1.Text = $"+ {My.Settings.Value1.ToString("N3")}"
If (Not My.Settings.ValueVisible1) Then
    ButtonValueDown1.Parent.Controls.Remove(ButtonValueDown1)
    ButtonValueUp1.Parent.Controls.Remove(ButtonValueUp1)

    With TableLayoutPanelDown.ColumnStyles.Item(0)
        .SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
        .Width = 0
    End With
    With TableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnStyles.Item(0)
        .SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
        .Width = 0
    End With
Else
    TableLayoutPanelDown.ColumnStyles.Item(0).Width = buttonWidth
    TableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnStyles.Item(0).Width = buttonWidth
End If
```

The issue that I'm running into is that whenever all 5 buttons are visible, the right-most Buttons in the top and bottom rows is flush with the TextBox in the middle row **but** whenever one or more of the Buttons are removed the right-most Buttons are no longer flush (see image).
[image: all buttons visible]
[image: one or more buttons removed]

What could be causing this? It is worth mentioning that all controls have a margin/padding of 0.

Comment: `TableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnStyles(0).SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize TableLayoutPanelUp.Refresh()`

Comment: I mean, assuming `TableLayoutPanelUp.Dock = Fill`.

Comment: @Jimi thank you, I'll try this whenever I get home tonight. My fear is that the buttons will not all be the same width (e.g. one will be much longer than the rest) and this is why I tried to set the percentage.

Comment: That's the reason for `.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize`. The TLP sets the percentage automatically.

Comment: @Jimi - Whenever I implement your suggestion, the buttons are all the same width but they're all smaller than the width of the size needed to fill up the remaining space. Not sure if its worth mentioning, but the TableLayoutPanel and the buttons are docked to fill and the TableLayoutPanel AutoSize is true.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure what you have setup in your visual example that is different than mine but my inner TLP no longer has the AutoSize but it still has Dock set to Fill, and the Button's set to fill. But I have a completely different behavior wherein the Button widths do not fill up the remaining space. Could it make a difference that I have this in my Form's Load where the controls haven't yet been rendered on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a TableLayoutPanel to resize its Columns dynamically at run-time, when Controls of an undefined size are added to the `TableLayoutPanel.Controls` collection, one effective method is to set, at design-time, the Columns' [TableLayoutStyle.SizeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutstyle.sizetype) to [SizeType.Percent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sizetype).
When adding Columns using the designer, we can set the `Percent` value of each new Column to `100%`. The TableLayoutPanel will automatically determine the correct percentage value, based on its current Size and the number of Columns added.

In the current scenario, we have an outer TableLayoutPanel with one Column that hosts other TableLayoutPanels in some of its Cells.
→ The inner TableLayoutPanels are set to `Dock = Fill`, filling the Cell they occupy.
→ The inner TLPs will host a variable number of Controls, so they need to dynamically adjust the size of the child Controls to fill the width of the outer TLP container.

Sample layout at design-time:

[image: TableLayoutPanel AutoSize DesignTime]

<sub>The upper, light gray, TableLayoutPanel in represent the **`tableLayoutPanelUp`** control in the sample code.</sub>

Since the child Controls (Buttons, here) are added and/or removed at run-time, the inner TableLayoutPanel needs to resize them evenly to fill the outer TableLayoutPanel container size, to preserve the layout.

► The TableLayoutPanel can perform this layout as expected, provided that we specify the Column and Row (the Cell) that will contain a Control when one is added to its `Controls` collection.
If we don't, the TableLayoutPanel cannot correctly determine the new size of its child Controls when it needs to resize them to fill the available space.

---

In the sample code, the child Buttons are added to a `List(Of Button)` collection (for convenience), then the Buttons are added to a TableLayoutPanel (named `tableLayoutPanelUp` as in the question).

■ The child Controls are added in a [SuspendLayout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout) / [PerformLayout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.performlayout) section, to suspend the layout until all Controls are added and then perform the layout when all *pieces* are in place.

■ for each new Control, its Cell position is set explicitly, using the TableLayoutPanel's [SetRow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow) and [SetColumn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumn) methods.

■ To remove a Control, the Control instance is specified using the **`Controls.Remove(Control)`** method (the Control is not disposed of, so it's still *inside* its container List) and the corresponding Column's **`ColumnStyles.Width`** (representing a `Percent` value) is set to `0`.

■ When a child Control is added, again the **`SetRow()`** and **`SetColumn()`** are called to define the Cell that will contain the new Control.  In this case, the Size (percentage) of the corresponding Column is set to **`100 / tableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnCount`**. Since the TableLayoutPanel is docked, this will force it to evaluate the new values and generate a new layout, recalculating all values to fit the docking requirements.

A visual sample of the result:

[image: TableLayoutPanel AutoSize Runtime]

<sub>In the sample code, the Add and Remove Buttons are named **`btnAddControl`** and **`btnRemoveControl`**, the ComboBox is named **`cboControlsIndexes`**</sub>

```
Private tlpButtons As List(Of Button) = Nothing

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    tlpButtons = New List(Of Button)() From {
        New Button() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, .Text = "Button1"},
        New Button() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, .Text = "Button2"},
        New Button() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, .Text = "Button3"},
        New Button() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, .Text = "Button4"},
        New Button() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, .Text = "Button5"}
    }

    cboControlsIndexes.DisplayMember = "Text"
    cboControlsIndexes.DataSource = tlpButtons

    tableLayoutPanelUp.SuspendLayout()

    For i As Integer = 0 To tlpButtons.Count - 1
        tableLayoutPanelUp.Controls.Add(tlpButtons(i))
        tableLayoutPanelUp.SetRow(tlpButtons(i), 0)
        tableLayoutPanelUp.SetColumn(tlpButtons(i), i)
    Next
    tableLayoutPanelUp.ResumeLayout(True)
    tableLayoutPanelUp.PerformLayout()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveControl.Click
    Dim removeAtIndex As Integer = cboControlsIndexes.SelectedIndex

    tableLayoutPanelUp.Controls.Remove(tlpButtons(removeAtIndex))
    tableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnStyles(removeAtIndex).Width = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddControl.Click
    Dim addAtIndex As Integer = cboControlsIndexes.SelectedIndex

    tableLayoutPanelUp.Controls.Add(tlpButtons(addAtIndex))
    tableLayoutPanelUp.SetRow(tlpButtons(addAtIndex), 0)
    tableLayoutPanelUp.SetColumn(tlpButtons(addAtIndex), addAtIndex)
    tableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnStyles(addAtIndex).Width = 100 / tableLayoutPanelUp.ColumnCount
End Sub
```