# How to adjust TableLayoutPanel to wrap content by height and weight? (dynamically)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I created a Form that I am going to use as pop-up.
I need that this pop-up contains title, ProgressBar and percentage text.

So, for this purpose, I choose to use `TableLayoutPanel` as a control in my Form.

All these UI elements are created in dynamically. For test now I am using Label instead of real ProgressBar.

```
public partial class TestFormDeleteIt : Form
{
    public TestFormDeleteIt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AutoSize = true;
        var flp = CreateTableLayoutPanel();
        Controls.Add(flp);
    }

    private Control CreateTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        // TableLayoutPanel Initialization
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            ColumnCount = 2,
            RowCount = 2,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        //Adjust column size in percentage
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 70F));
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30F));

        //Adjust row size in percentage
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));

        //Fill content
        panel.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                Text = "state",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            }, 
            /*column*/ 0, /*row*/ 0);

        panel.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                Text = "ProgressBar",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            },
            /*column*/ 0, /*row*/ 1);

        panel.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                Text = "100%",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            }, 
            /*column*/ 1, /*row*/ 1);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I create `TableLayoutPanel` divided by rows and columns and for each view that it holds I set `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, because I don't want to hardcode a fixed size.

What am I expecting is that each UI element fills a Cell in the TableLayoutPanel and the parent Form itself will adjust its size by the TableLayoutPanel that holds all the other Controlss.

But actually I get this result:

[image]

The Parent Form doesn't wrap content, it looks like it has fixed size and the TableLayoutPanel tries to fill the Form ClientArea. I've set `AutoSize = true;`, but it has no visible affect.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks, @Jimi now it looks like much better

[image]

I also added

```
MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(600, Height)
```

to TLP, but question is - as you can see each row has like min height. And it looks like space between each row. Why is it happens?

**EDIT2**

I would like to notice that if I change this

```
panel.Controls.Add(
    new Label()
    {
        Text = "state",
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    },
    /*column*/ 0, /*row*/ 0);
```

to this:

```
var label1 = new Label()
{
    Text = "state",
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

panel.SetRow(label1, 0);
panel.SetColumn(label1, 0);
```

it doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

and here is my code now

```
public partial class TestFormDeleteIt : Form
{
    public TestFormDeleteIt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AutoSize = true;
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 0);

        var flp = CreateTableLayoutPanel();
        Controls.Add(flp);
    }

    private TableLayoutPanel CreateTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        // TableLayoutPanel Initialization
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            ColumnCount = 2,
            RowCount = 2,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        //Adjust column size in percentage
        panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 90F));
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10F));

        //Adjust row size in percentage
        panel.RowStyles.Clear();
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));

        //Fill content
        panel.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                Text = "state",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            },
            /*column*/ 0, /*row*/ 0);

        panel.Controls.Add(
            CreateProgressBar(),
            /*column*/ 0, /*row*/ 1);

        panel.Controls.Add(
            new Label()
            {
                Text = "100%",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            }, 
            /*column*/ 1, /*row*/ 1);

        panel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        panel.AutoSize = true;

        return panel;
    }

    private Control CreateProgressBar() => new ProgressBar()
    {
        Visible = true,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top
    };
}
```

Problem is - that even if I set static width as 200 -> `MinimumSize = new Size(200, 0)` in my Form, when I open it I see that it takes like `1000`.

[image]

Why is it happens?

Comment: Remove `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` from the TLP. Set the Form's `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`. Also (precaution): `panel.ColumnStyles.Clear(); panel.RowStyles.Clear();` before setting the new styles. I'd suggest to declare the `TableLayoutPanel` as an instance Field (it's declared locally now). The overall new size of the Form is pre-cooked, so set it to something else if you need to.

Comment: I also suggest to set a Control's `Column` and `Row` explicitly, using the `SetColumn()` and `SetRow()` methods.

Comment: @Jimi edited my question, and also would like to ask you what do you mean about `SetColumn()` and `SetRow()` methods? Like this `panel.SetRow(panel, 2)` ? But what is the advantage?

Comment: The same way you create `var panel = new TableLayoutPanel()`, you create a child control: `var label = new Label() { ... }`. Then you can set `panel.SetColumn(label, 1)` and `panel.SetRow(label, 0)`. Maybe you don't know why right now, but keep it in mind if child Controls begin to behave erratically at some point (not with this simple layout; a more complex one, when you add and remove Controls dynamically. But it should be something you do no matter what).

Comment: @Jimi aa, tnx! Did you see my edit in quesiton?

Comment: If you don't like the default spacing, you can set `[TableLayoutPanel].AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;` and `[TableLayoutPanel].AutoSize = true;` **after** you have added the child Controls. The child Controls Margin property determine the distance between them. Note that your `CreateTableLayoutPanel()` method should return a `TableLayoutPanel` type, not Control (...)

Comment: (...) When your method returns, the Form's `MinimumSize` can also be set as `new Size(600, 0);`: in this case, the Width is *static*, while the Height is *dynamic* (`0` mean *as needed*). This allows you to set the TLP `Dock = Fill` after you have added it to the `Form.Controls` collection, if that's make a better layout in your view.

Comment: @Jimi edited my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: It's in the comments: when the `CreateTableLayoutPanel()` method returns, set `tlp.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink; tlp.AutoSize = true;`. Then add the TLP to `Form.Controls`, then `tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: @Jimi I think I make something wrong because nothing changed. I will appreciate if you publish your answer. Because I think that I miss something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The scenario**:

- A bare-bones Form, no specific dimensions applied. No child controls.
- A [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) is build from scratch at run-time. No specific dimensions

  - Two Rows and two Columns are created with size mode set to percentage
  - Three Control are created from scratch and added to three of the TableLayoutPanel's Cells
    The TableLayoutPanel must resize itself to the new content, which doesn't have a specific size (except the default size applied to the Windows Forms Controls), without *squeezing* out of existence the new child Controls
- The Form, after the TableLayoutPanel is added to its Controls collection, must auto-size itself to the size of its (only) child Control, keeping a newly set minimum Width, but no minimum or maximum Height (so it can expand vertically, if needed, but not horizontally)
- Finally, the auto-sized TableLayoutPanel must be docked inside the auto-sized Form container and all parts need to cooperate to generate the expected Layout

**How to proceed**:

The sequence of the *operations* will clearly determine the final result.

1. The Form initializes: it's construtor calls the standard InitializeComponent() method. There are no child Controls, so there's actually nothing to layout. The Form will simply set the Size defined in the Designer.
2. We now instruct the Form to AutoSize to its content and also that it's allowed to both grow and shrink its Size to accomplish this task. The Form won't actually do anything right now, since it cannot perform its Layout at this time (unless explicitly instructed, using the `PerformLayout()` method)
3. We set a minimum Size, constraining its Width, but not its Height (setting **`MinimumSize = new Size(200, 0)`**, we define a minimum Width, but the Height dimension is free to grow and also shrink, here - setting `0` as value, means *no restrictions*).
4. The TableLayoutPanel and its child Controls are now created, using default Sizes (Windows Forms Controls have a default Size when created). The Labels will AutoSize to the size of their Text: this is the default behavior.
5. After all child Controls are added to the TLP, the TLP is instructed to AutoSize itself, also specifying that it can grow and shrink to perform the Layout.
6. The TableLayoutPanel is added to the Form container. Now, when a Control is added to the Controls collection, the internal method instructs the ContainerControl to **`SuspendLayout()`**, position the new Control and **`ResumeLayou()`** (without also performing the Layout of the child Controls, since this has just happened): at this point, the Form, instructed to AutoSize to its content, will calculate its `PreferredSize` and then auto-size itself to the new content.
7. The `TableLayoutPanel` is now set to Dock to the parent Container. The Container is already auto-sized to the size of the `TableLayoutPanel`, so the TLP just fixes its anchors to the current Size of the Form.

The final Layout will be performed before the Form is shown: anyway, at this point, all the Controls involved are already sized and positioned as instructed.

**Extra**:

▶ The TableLayoutPanel's [SetColumn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumn) and [SetRow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow) are called explicitly. The reason is partailly explained in the Remarks section of the two methods:

> *This method **reapplies** the table layout to all controls in the
> TableLayoutPanel.*

In the current context, calling these methods is a *plus*. It's not strictly needed, because we just add Controls to the TLP, never remove one.
But, when Controls are added to and removed from the TLP while the TLP is set to AutoSize to its content (this applies to the current context), the TLP won't actually perform the Layout as expected: the Cells will, in most cases (yes, not always...) maintain their original Size when a Control is removed (removed or disposed, the result is the same).

Some notes on the matter are found here:
<sub>This code (different language but simple to read) can easily tested to reproduce the *problem*</sub>
[Dynamic TableLayoutPanel Controls Keep Border Width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618529/7444103)

▶ The [ColumnStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles) and [RowStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles) are cleared and new styles are added:
- The original code actually adds new styles without removing the existing, default, ones: this can and will generate a layout problem in some situations.  Some notes on the matter here:

[Remove Row inside TableLayoutPanel makes a layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225457/7444103)
[Center multiple rows of controls in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103)

---

```
public partial class TestFormDeleteIt : Form
{
    protected internal ProgressBar pBar = null;
    protected internal Label lbl2 = null;

    public TestFormDeleteIt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 0);

        var tlp = CreateTableLayoutPanel();

        tlp.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        tlp.AutoSize = true;

        this.Controls.Add(tlp);
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Run(() => UpdateProgress());
    }

    private TableLayoutPanel CreateTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel { ColumnCount = 2, RowCount = 2,
            CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single
        };
        panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        panel.RowStyles.Clear();

        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 70F));
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30F));

        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));

        var lbl1 = new Label() { Text = "state", Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        panel.Controls.Add(lbl1);
        panel.SetColumn(lbl1, 0);
        panel.SetRow(lbl1, 0);

        pBar = new ProgressBar() { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        panel.Controls.Add(pBar);
        panel.SetColumn(pBar, 0);
        panel.SetRow(pBar, 1);

        lbl2 = new Label() { Text = "0%", Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        panel.Controls.Add(lbl2);
        panel.SetColumn(lbl2, 1);
        panel.SetRow(lbl2, 1);

        return panel;
    }

    private async Task UpdateProgress()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                pBar.Value = i;
                lbl2.Text = (i / 100.0).ToString("P");
            }));
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }
}
```